# AWS - Dynamodb get latency is too high in global tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table called Environment in eu-west-2 region and replicated this table in us-east-2 and ap-east-1 regions. The table contains only 10 records and total table size is less than 2KB. Read latency in eu-west-2 is 2ms (around 120 requests / minute) whereas other two regions and a get latency of more than 12ms(around 50 requests / minute in each of these regions).  There was no throttling in any of the regions. All the configurations are same  and I'm not able to figure out this huge difference in the latency. What could possibly be the reason?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you doing the reads from? Are these the CloudWatch metrics from the table? Is the capacity identical?

Comment: I'm reading from a lambda located in the same region as that of dynamodb table.

Comment: That answers about 33% of my questions, whats the memory configuration of the different lambda functions?

Comment: @Maurice - 1. From lambda functions. 2. Yes, cloudwatch metrics from dynamodb tables 3. No. eu-west-2 where latency is 2ms has 3GB memory. us-east-2 has 4GB and ap-east-1 has 3GB.

Answer (score 0):

I had to define the dynamodb boto3 client outside the local scope in the lambda. It was inside a function and a new client was getting created on every request. Moving the client object outside the local scope and defining outside the lambda function as a global variable resolved the latency issue.